# How to detect when jQuery global variable is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried doing it using the method below.  However because jQuery has not been defined I get a -

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

from Firefox.

I was hoping it would have been undefined and testable not error producing.

If I define a dummy variable like this `var jQuery`, then when I use jQuery I will always be using that blank variable due to scope look-up rules.

*How do I detect when the jQuery global variable is ready?*

```
    // ... snip

    if (jQuery) { // not defined - I guess different from undefined - always errors

    // ...snip
```

Comment: Check for jQuery in the `window`.

Comment: I've rolled back the last edit as it made the question very hard to understand and I could not see how ThiefMaster was able to get to the answer he came to from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(window.jQuery !== undefined)
```

or

```
if(typeof jQuery !== 'undefined')
```

However, the first version is more readable in my opinion and in a browser environment `window` is the global object so `window.X` is pretty much equivalent to the global `X` - except the fact that trying to access an undefined `window.X` will not throw an error.

Comment: Interesting that you can do `typeof` without getting reference errors!

Comment: True, but pretty simple when you look at the spec: http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.3 - *If `IsUnresolvableReference(val)` is true, return `"undefined"`.*